# Changing position of scrollbar in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

Hey I was wondering if it is possible to change the position of the scroll bar in Android RecyclerView. I would like to move the scroll bar closer to the right side of the display. If someone could just point me in the right direction with a link or something I would really appreciate that because currently I can't find anything on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only one workaround idea,

you can add to your main content layout only top and bottom padding (or margin).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingTop="4dp"
  android:paddingBottom="4dp">
```

Then RecyclerView without defining styles, like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/cardList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

and if you use CardView or other element, you can add left and right borders to him, then scrollbar keep on right side and element is not until the edges:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="6dp">
```